# Two different combination value decided by the id in ComboBox

Tags: c#

I got two Combobox, one Textbox and one Button.

I want the value in the TextBox to be set from `Combobox2`, by what I choose in `Combobox1`. The `id` in "List Machnie" should change what is suppose to be viewing in the TextBox. For example,

- If I choose "Machine 1" (id=1) in `combobox1` together with "Yarn 1" in `combobox2`, it should be showing the number "1" in the TextBox.
- If I choose "Machine 2" (id=2) in `combobox1` together with "Yarn 1" in `combobox2`, it should be showing the number "2" in the TextBox.
- If I choose "Machine 1" (id=1) in `combobox1` together with "Yarn 2" in `combobox2`, it should be showing the number "3" in the TextBox.
- If I choose "Machine 2" (id=2) in `combobox1` together with "Yarn 2" in `combobox2`, it should be showing the number "4" in the TextBox.

How do I make this to work?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Machine> ft = new List<Machine>();
        ft.Add(new Machine() { id = 1, bredd = 10, hojd = 15, Name = "Machine 1" });
        ft.Add(new Machine() { id = 2, bredd = 20, hojd = 25, Name = "Machine 2" });
        ft.Add(new Machine() { id = 1, bredd = 30, hojd = 35, Name = "Machine 3" });
        ft.Add(new Machine() { id = 2, bredd = 40, hojd = 45, Name = "Machine 4" });
        comboBox2.DataSource = ft;
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";

        List<Yarn> ft3 = new List<Yarn>();
        ft3.Add(new Yarn() { meter = 1, weight = 2, Name = "Yarn 1" });
        ft3.Add(new Yarn() { meter = 3, weight = 4, Name = "Yarn 2" });
        comboBox1.DataSource = ft3;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Machine ft1 = comboBox2.SelectedItem as Machine;
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(ft1.id);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

class Machine
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int bredd { get; set; }
    public int hojd { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Yarn
{
    public int meter { get; set; }
    public int weight { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And what problem you are facing,?

Comment: Error with "if.id = 1.Show (meter = 1), if.id = 2.Show (meter = 2)".I want it to show the value 1 from "meter=" depending on what id there is in the other combobox.

Comment: It is clear what you want... But it is not clear what problem you are facing so not sure what solution to suggest. In `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` you should check values of both combo box and then decide the value for text box.

Comment: I don't know how to write "meter = 1), if.id = 2.Show (meter = 2" so it works. Also. When looking on "comboBox1_SelevtedIndexChanged", I don't understand how I can call the id so it shows the number from "meter"

Comment: I tried to use your code to reproduce the issue but the code doesn't even compile... there are lot of errors in that... Can you share the code without any errors?

Comment: Okey, I have added "textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(ft1.id);" so it sees the id number but from "machine", but how do I add a "call command" so it will show the right "meter" from "yarn" (right "meter" from by id)?

Comment: I updated with the script that "works". "textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(ft1.id);" is it possible to get "1" from meter, when id is 1 and "2" if the id is 2?

Comment: I have also tried "textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(ft1.id=1, WriteLine(yarn.meter)" but that gives me an error also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think the easiest way to achieve that is to add one more property in both classes say *CombineValue* that defines the item's combine value.

Give it a try:

```
class Machine
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int bredd { get; set; }
    public int hojd { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CombineValue { get; set; }
}

class Yarn
{
    public int meter { get; set; }
    public int weight { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CombineValue { get; set; }
}
```

Create your objects and populate them:

```
List<Machine> ft = new List<Machine>();
ft.Add(new Machine() { id = 1, bredd = 10, hojd = 15, Name = "Machine 1", CombineValue = 1 });
ft.Add(new Machine() { id = 2, bredd = 20, hojd = 25, Name = "Machine 2", CombineValue = 2 });
ft.Add(new Machine() { id = 1, bredd = 30, hojd = 35, Name = "Machine 3", CombineValue = 3 });
ft.Add(new Machine() { id = 2, bredd = 40, hojd = 45, Name = "Machine 4", CombineValue = 4 });
cmbMachine.DataSource = ft;
cmbMachine.DisplayMember = "Name";

List<Yarn> ft3 = new List<Yarn>();
ft3.Add(new Yarn() { meter = 1, weight = 2, Name = "Yarn 1", CombineValue = 1 });
ft3.Add(new Yarn() { meter = 3, weight = 4, Name = "Yarn 2", CombineValue = 2 });
cmbYarn.DataSource = ft3;
cmbYarn.DisplayMember = "Name";

CombinValues(); // <- See below :
```

Create a function to do the calculation and outputs the result:

```
private void CombinValues()
{
    var m = cmbMachine.SelectedItem as Machine;
    var y = cmbYarn.SelectedItem as Yarn;

    txt.Text = (m.CombineValue + y.CombineValue).ToString();
}
```

Call the function from the *SelectionChangeCommitted* events of both combos:

```
private void cmbMachine_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CombinValues();
}

private void cmbYarn_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CombinValues();
}
```

That's all. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! You just solved my problem! Thank you so much again.

Comment: Glad to hear that and thank you for your support. Keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

Got it almost solved, thank you all. But when changing "ComboBox2" first and then "ComboBox1", I need to change ComboBox2 again to get the textbox refreshed/updated with the right value.

```
            Yarn ft4 = comboBox1.SelectedItem as Yarn;
        Machine ft1 = comboBox2.SelectedItem as Machine;
        if (ft1.id == 1)
        {  
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(ft4.weight);}
         else if (ft1.id == 2)
         {
            YarnSizeTextbox.Text = Convert.ToString(ft3.meter);
        }
```